# Simulate network tutorial produces output that is different from the tutorial

Tags: substrate-node-template

In particular the Initializing Genesis block/state is missing from the output along with some other details.

Tutorial:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/

Start Alice node:

```
   % ./target/release/node-template \                                               
    --base-path /tmp/alice \
    --chain local \
    --alice \
    --port 30333 \
    --ws-port 9945 \
    --rpc-port 9933 \
    --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
    --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
    --validator


2022-07-27 13:15:15 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-07-27 13:15:15 creating instance on iface 192.168.7.213    
2022-07-27 13:15:20  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-07-27 13:15:25  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-07-27 13:15:30  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-07-27 13:15:35  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-07-27 13:15:35 ❌ Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout }    
2022-07-27 13:15:40  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-07-27 13:15:45  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x004c…08f7), finalized #0 (0x004c…08f7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

Expected similar output from tutorial:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to this issue here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11855

Try:

```
cargo update -p tracing-core --precise 0.1.26
```

Then re-run your node again.